# Rsync for Android: with Google Drive and Github

Tags: backup, google-backup, open-source

I am looking for a way to sync a folder that contains files created by an app, where the app doesn't have backup capabilities.

I want the folder to be synced either with Google Drive, or, better, with GitHub (so that my files will be preserved in revision history even if they are deleted on my smartphone's directory).

Is there such a service on Android? Would I have better have asked this on Software Recommendations?

Thanks.